# Manipulating/Automating a web page from a Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**Is it possible to manipulate a loaded page of an open tab of Firefox, through a script that does this through a Firefox addon/extension**? My goal is to fill out a form on a page, and then click submit.

Note: This cannot be done through readily available, 'user friendly' alternatives (for example Selenium), and can only be done with addon code, as the Firefox addon continuously calls a .dll file, waiting for an 'all clear, go ahead' from another program, that communicates with the .dll file. Also, solutions such as Selenium, take up too much processing time (even when we are dealing with seconds), which do not suit my case (i have already attempted using Selenium; it completes the task too slowly, and the .dll workaround is 'awkward').

So the question is, is possible to achieve something like this, and what will be required to do so, could you also please provide an example if possible. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK

Comment: What about iMacros its already a firefox addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/

Comment: You can try attaching a content script to all the `existing tabs`, by using page-mod API. There's an `attachTo` option for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29